# Early-1990s basic D&D adventure - had three dragons in a ruined keep of squabbling mooks

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, published-adventures, product-identification

This was a DnD adventure I recall playing in the early 90s.

There were three adventures all closely connected: a black dragon, a green dragon (which uses illusions to make itself seem like three dragons together), and a red dragon. There was also a ruined keep filled with squabbling mook races, like goblins, orcs, etc. The dragons had to keep the peace among the tribes, and the lieutenants included a goblin leader and a harpy or siren. Her name was something similar to "Hauraura".

This would have been 1990 to 1993.

Comment: Do you happen to remember the edition that you were playing at the time? Adding that tag should help connect this question with experts in the specific edition.

Comment: Oh, and Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: Was this a stand-alone published adventure, or, was it in the Dungeon Magazine, or Dragon Magazine, as an adventure offered from the Magazine?

Comment: It was in the edition of DnD that coexisted with AD&D 2nd Ed. I recall that I bought the AD&D books and my friend bought the DnD books, and I think this was an adventure in the DnD edition. The adventure came with a big color map of the ruined keep.

Answer (score 1):

### The AD&D Dragonlance adventure modules series

A possible match appears in the AD&D *Dragonlance* adventure module series, originally published in the mid-1980s and collected into three *Dragonlance Classics* volumes in 1993 and 1994, each containing four of the original adventure modules.

These may match your recollection as follows:

- In DL9 *Dragons of Deceit*, there is a ruined fortress called Solanthus, now garrisoned by hundreds of goblins and Bozak draconians. There is also a red dragon named Harkiel, and an elf fighter NPC named Laurana, which could be the name you remember.
- In DL10 *Dragons of Dreams*, the PCs fight Cyan Bloodbane, a green dragon. He appears standing over King Lorac's throne, using illusion to make it appear that there are five dragons. There is a sirine named Kiiren, chained to the top of a pillar. Note that this is a *sirine*, not a *siren*, an aquatic fey creature.

However, I am uncertain as to which module might contain the black dragon you remember.

Comment: Thanks, it seems very familiar and I think they may have republished the Dragonlance adventures in a DnD mega-adventure pack or similar.